# Let $A$ be the event that either a $6$ or $2$ is rolled first, followed by an odd number. Then $P(A)=?$

Tags: probability, statistics

$2$ fair dice are rolled in succession.
With $(1,3)$ denoting values $1$ on the first roll and $3$ on the second...etc. Let $A$ be the event that either a $6$ or $2$ is rolled first, followed by an odd number. Then $P(A)=?$. What shall I do first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of rolling a 2 or 6 on a fair die is $1/3$ and the probability of rolling an odd number (so 1, 3 or 5) is $1/2$. Since these two events are independent, $P(A) = 1/2 \cdot 1/3 = 1/6$.

In general with problems like these, you can sometimes split up the event $A$ into more manageable parts (divide and conquer) that are independent and then simply multiply the probabilities.